# How to show edited Row and before edited row in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

I am working with ASP.NET and SQL Server 2012.

I have a form which has operation like *Insert*, *Update* and *Delete*.

While using *Update*, I need to display 2 rows; one row displaying previous row on which update has been performed, and the second row will be the updated row.

I am sharing my table column headings.

```
ServiceTaxCode  Name    Location    CentralisedRegDate  SurrenderDate

AA              ARMI    mumbai      2015-03-10          2016-04-03
```

Comment: I used datatabel, first i feed the previous row in datatable then after updation i added the  updated row as second row in datatable and showed the datatable in gridview.